# stop hidden div flashing up on screen as page loads in jquery

Tags: jquery, hide

I am using

```
$(function() {
    $('#div1, #div2, #div3').hide();
```

at the beginning of my script and later using .fadeIn() to fade them in. However, they are appearing for a split second on screen in IE as the page loads. Is there some way to prevent this?

Answer (score 5):

put the following attribute on each div:

```
<div id="div1" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Comment: Inline styling is not such a good practice, and using a CSS class like `hidden` will enable you to remove that class once your display stops arranging itself.

Answer (score 4):

Add "display:none" to the CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
        #divs {
            display:none
        }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're not too worried about users who have JS disabled, you can always just hide it with CSS.

Another option would be to put that code directly beneath the DIVs so they are executed the moment the DIV is loaded and don't have to wait till the whole DOM is loaded. I don't really like this option as you're going to have JS interspersed with your HTML

Answer (score 0):

put

```
'class/id' { visibility: hidden; }
```

in the css file and also make sure this is written at top, before asigning any styling to that div
or else it might flash div before hiding it

or else you can just

```
<div style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
```

in html itself

it worked for me

Comment: visibility: hidden will still cause issues as it does not remove the space occupied by the div. so if it takes space then there will be a layout shift instead of div flashing.